# Print out unicode char from within string in terminal C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode

When printing out a string containing a unicode character to the terminal, the unicode char shows up correctly. But when I try to isolate the unicode char into a string and print it out, it prints as a "?". How can I extract the unicode char from the string and place it in a new string without losing its unicode memory?

text is a global std::string

This is how I'm pulling the unicode char out:

```
stringstream ss;
string ret = "";
ss << text[index];
ss >> ret;
```

Also I cannot use wchar, wstring, or any std library having to do with unicode.

Comment: what is `text` as type? That's the important info here!

Comment: it is std::string

Comment: What encoding is it, `UTF-8`?

Comment: Also what is the string?

Answer (score 1):

```
ss << text[index];
```

My guess is that `text` is a C String or something else that actually uses bytes (aka. `char` in C and C++) as storage. So your `[]` index operation doesn't give you the whole unicode codepoint, but only one byte of it.

**Edit** you've added

> "I cannot use … any std library having to do with unicode"

That is a bullshit requirement. It means you have to reimplement unicode functionality, and that's a) huge thing and b) a bringer of bugs. So, for everything that is proper: you're using `std::stringstream`, you can just as as well use wide characters and the like.

Comment: How would I get the whole thing?

Comment: Guess why I asked under your question what the type of `text` is... it depends on that!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `UTF-8` the problem is that individual `UTF-8` characters can occupy between `1` to `4` bytes (and theoretically `6`).

In order to iterate through them you need to calculate the size of each character. The following code uses a simple table but you can also get creative with bit manipulations:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// return individual utf-8 chars as a vector of strings
std::vector<std::string> utf8_split_chars(std::string const& s)
{
    // table to get the size of a utf-8 character
    static const char u8char_size[] =
    {
          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
        , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
        , 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
        , 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 0, 0
    };

    std::vector<std::string> utf8_chars;

    // increment the index i by the size of each utf-8 char
    for(auto i = 0U; i < s.size(); i += u8char_size[(unsigned char)s[i]])
    {
        utf8_chars.emplace_back(&s[i], u8char_size[(unsigned char)s[i]]);
    }

    return utf8_chars;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = u8"建造 otoño κάτω";

    std::cout << "s: " << s <<" " << s.size() << " bytes" << '\n';

    auto chars = utf8_split_chars(s);

    for(auto const& c: chars)
        std::cout << "c: " << c << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
s: 建造 otoño κάτω 22 bytes
c: 建
c: 造
c:  
c: o
c: t
c: o
c: ñ
c: o
c:  
c: κ
c: ά
c: τ
c: ω
```